# Import UTF-8 BOM CSV using Laravel Excel package

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-excel

I'm trying to import a simple CSV file using the `[SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel][1]` package. The CSV looks like this:

```
Name,Time,Amount (ml),Note
Dave Smith,"14/08/2022, 22:18",60
Sarah Jones,"14/08/2022, 18:00",100
Mark Brown,"14/08/2022, 13:54",100
```

My import file contains this function:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    dd($row);
}
```

However the file is not parsed properly, the above code returns:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "Name,Time,Amount"
  1 => "(ml),Note"
  2 => null
]
```

When I query the file using Terminal and get the following:

```
'my_file.csv: Unicode text, UTF-8 (with BOM) text'
```

Its definitely related to the encoding because if I resave the csv as "csv text" it parses properly. Changing the "input_encoding" to "UTF-8" and "use_bom" to true makes no difference. The CSV is output by a program I do not control so cannot change the format or contents. How can I properly import a UTF-8 BOM csv into Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add the delimiter in the excel.php config file, change

```
'delimiter'        => '',
```

to

```
'delimiter'        => ',',
```